# Weird issue on IE (IE9 and lower) with JavaScript (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am experiencing a weird problem on IE (IE 9 and lower).

I have a form having a select and a radio. When anyone changes anything in the select or radio, it calculates the total price.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Debiprasad/DLQ82/8/

It works fine in all browsers. But when I am testing this on IE: When I am changing the select value, then it works fine. But when I am changing the value radio, then it does not work.

The weird part is, if I added an alert to any of the functions, which executed when the value of radio changes, then it works fine on IE.
What could be the problem and how to fix this?

Comment: I was able to run the jsFiddle without any problems using IE9. Do you have code somewhere that might be causing this?

Comment: Runs fine for me in IE8 and IE7 mode

Comment: @James Johnson, epascarello: he did mention the code he shared is working in IE - "the code shared via jsfiddle.net works fine on IE".
He should be posting non-working code instead.

Comment: Yes, I also checked that before posting. I don't have any other code, which should conflict. The weird part is, when I add any alert to any of those two functions, it works on IE. I have to find out the issue myself, just shared, whether anyone has similar weird experience and can share their thoughts.

Comment: @Debiprasad If the code you shared works fine in IE, then there's no way someone is going to help you figure out why it's not working in IE.

Comment: You should probably just use `var quantity = $('#oa_quantity').val();`, the id must be unique across the page and will always be selected before anything else.

Comment: Being that the jsFiddle works fine and you code doesn't, we're able to deduce that the problem resides somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IE, the change event on radio and checkbox controls only fires when the element [loses focus](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-193-onchange-does-not-fire-properly.html), unlike other browsers.

I think jQuery fixed their `change` event to use `propertychange` in IE some time ago, you can see this by changing the jQuery version in jsFiddle to 1.3.2 and observing the different behaviour.  Which version of jQuery are you using locally?

Comment: Looks like this is the solution. I am using jQuery 1.3.2 on the website. And selected 1.6.4 on jsfiddle. It does not work with jQuery 1.3.2 on IE.